# How to programatically get the value of a field from a sql query?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm writing a script to query the t_object and t_objectproperties tables and iterate on the result elements.
This actually fairly simple. I'm using this:

```
function find_model_doc() {
var query = "select o.Object_ID, o.Name, op.Value from t_objectproperties op inner join (select * from t_object where stereotype = 'model document') o on o.Object_ID = op.Object_ID where op.Property = 'RTFTemplate'"
var all_modeldocs = Repository.GetElementSet(query, 2);
for (var o = 0; o < all_modeldocs.Count; o++) {
    elem_name = all_modeldocs.GetAt(o).Name;
    elem_value = all_modeldocs.GetAt(o).Value;
    Session.Output("name|value: " + elem_name + " | " + elem_value)
}}
```

If I use this query in the 'SQL scratch pad' I get:
[image]

However, with the script I can't seem to get the strings from the 'Value' field.
Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `EA.Repository.GetElementSet(query, 2)` returns an `EA.Collection` with items of type `EA.Element`. It does so based upon the Object_ID returned by your query. All other returned values are ignored.

These objects don't have a `Value` property.

What you seem to be looking for, is value of the tagged values with name "RTFTemplate" defined on the element.

You can do that in two ways

### Iterate the tagged values of the elements returned by GetElementSet

Something like this (vbscript)

```
for each element in all_modeldocs
    elem_name = element.Name
    for each tag in element.TaggedValues
        if tag.Name = "RTFTemplate" then
            elem_value : tag.Value
        end if
    next
next
```

### Use Repository.SQLQuery and parse the resulting xml string

Something like this (vbscript)

```
function getArrayListFromQuery(sqlQuery)
    dim xmlResult
    xmlResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sqlQuery)
    set getArrayListFromQuery = convertQueryResultToArrayList(xmlResult)
end function

Function convertQueryResultToArrayList(xmlQueryResult)
    Dim result
    set result = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim xDoc 
    Set xDoc = CreateObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument" )
    'load the resultset in the xml document
    If xDoc.LoadXML(xmlQueryResult) Then        
        'select the rows
        Dim rowList
        Set rowList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Row")
        Dim rowNode 
        Dim fieldNode
        'loop rows and find fields
        For Each rowNode In rowList
            dim rowArrayList
            set rowArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
            'loop the field nodes
            For Each fieldNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
                'add the contents
                rowArrayList.Add fieldNode.Text
            Next
            'add the row the the general list
            result.Add rowArrayList
        Next
    end if
    set convertQueryResultToArrayList = result
end function
```

Comment: Perfect! I used the 1st approach you described and got the result I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ice comments like this are completely useless. If you have a question please post an actual question.